# terminate screen monitoring serial port

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port, serial-console

I am using `screen /dev/tty-MyDevice` to look at traffic on my serial port.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does not cause the screen to terminate.

What I have to do in order to terminate it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the [screen quit command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Quit.html#Quit) (normally <kbd>ctrl-A</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd>).

Comment: Ctrl+a Ctrl+-, yields a blank screen, Ctrl+a Ctrl+c yields a new screen, which Ctrl+D then is able to exit like all other screens I've encountered before this.

Comment: Oops, markdown turned my "ctrl-\" into "ctrl-". Fixed.

Comment: It worked as Ctrl-a \ (that is Ctrl-a and then plain \ without ctrl). Strange that the link provided includes a Ctrl for the \.

Comment: This kind of works, but when connecting to a qemu serial pty this really kills it. That means I can't reconnect to it after that. With picocom, I can easily terminate the serial connection and reconnect later.

Comment: `CTRL-A` `k` `y` Is better because it doesn't "quit" all of screen, just "kills" the current tab, which may or may not be the last tab.

Answer (score 14):

I run all my terminals inside a screen, and also sometimes use screen to connect to serial.  If you `screen /dev/ttyUSB0` inside screen, you'll just get a new window in your current session, not a new child screen.

In this case, press `Ctrl-A k` to kill only the current window rather than the entire screen process and your other windows with it.  This is the kill window command.

Answer (score 10):

Though aecolley's answer usually works then it did not work for me (could be because of Icelandic keyboard and Icelandic locale, but somehow doubt it). When in that situation then you can go to a different console and execute `screen -ls` and take note of the screen session number, the output should be something like this:

```
There is a screen on:
            6254.tty2.hostname           (Attached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root
```

The screen session number her is then 6254.

Then you can issue the following command to close that screen session: `screen -X -S 6254 quit`

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue turned out to be that I had inadvertently logged out of the Linux user account, and not the system I was controlling through the serial port. Once I logged back in, all of the normal `screen` commands such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> began working again.

Beyond that, if you can open a new `screen` window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>), another TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1..12</kbd>, or an SSH session, then you can run `pkill screen` or `kill <PID of screen>`.